# How many buildings can I buy per turn in Queendomino?

Tags: untagged

The instructions state you can

> (Optional) Construct a building on an open red construction square.

I am assuming the convention is that you can buy one building per moved Meeple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [rules](http://www.blueorangegames.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/QUEENDOMINO_rules_ML.pdf),

> You must take the **following actions, in the outlined order** (Note that only actions A and E are mandatory. The rest are optional):

you can see that you can play each action at most 1 times.

For action C (Building):

> C - (Optional) **Construct a Building**:You need to have at least 1 “Town”
>   square still in construction in order to construct a building, whether
>   this is a square that was added to your territory during a previous
>   round or the current one.

It clearly states a building, so you can only construct one for action C and because there is only one (or none) action C in your turn, you can only construct one building per turn.

Comment: ugh, what if your last play is a double red???